# How do I import numeric data as text?

Tags: stata

I have identification numbers such as `7612245235086` that I need to import from a `csv` file into Stata.

However, when I import them, they end up in scientific notation.

How do I import them but keep them as text values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `stringcols()` option of the `import delimited` command:

```
tempname myfile
file open `myfile' using "example.csv", write text replace

file write `myfile' "7612245235086" _n
file write `myfile' "8612245235087" _n
file write `myfile' "9612245235088" _n
file close `myfile'

import delimited using example.csv, clear
list

     +-----------+
     |        v1 |
     |-----------|
  1. | 7.612e+12 |
  2. | 8.612e+12 |
  3. | 9.612e+12 |
     +-----------+

import delimited using example.csv, clear stringcols(_all)
list

     +---------------+
     |            v1 |
     |---------------|
  1. | 7612245235086 |
  2. | 8612245235087 |
  3. | 9612245235088 |
     +---------------+

erase example.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for the accept. Please also consider up-voting my answer with the upper arrow :)